# Pattern filled background is not exporting to SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, patterns

I am trying to draw some electromechanic components in SVG format files.

In the example below, you can see the symbol for one of these components in which I have filled the squares with a linear pattern.

[image]

I have tried to do this with MS Visio and with Adobe Illustrator:

1. In MS Visio, the pattern is shown in the exported SVG but they are not real vectorial lines, but bitmap. So when I zoom in the image the result is very ugly.
2. In the other hand, in Illustrator, the pattern is complety obviated during the exporting process as you can see in the image.

[image]

I understand that I can solve this issue by drawing the pattern by myself, but since the lines are not vertical neither horizontal it is not easy to work with them (distribute proportionally, adjust it to the borders of the squares ...).

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and `Object` > `Expand` your pattern before saving it as an `.svg`. That way, the pattern is converted into actual objects, and those are bound to show up in your export.

Comment: It works! Thanks! The thing now is that the software guys still have problems with getting the paths (I really do not have a clue... everything new for me). Anyway, you solved my answer so you got the acceptance.

Comment: maybe their problem is that the paths are too thin?

Comment: I really don't know. We have put this issue in standby for the moment.